# Why is a return required when Environment.Exit() is used, but not for a thrown exception?

Tags: c#, exception, compiler-errors, return, throw

I'm trying to better understand the compiler for C#. It insists that all code paths must return a value, and I think that's pretty fair.

It also recognizes that if an exception is thrown in a path where a value would need to be returned, that there is no point in returning something there. This also makes sense.

My question is: **why wouldn't this also apply for exiting the program in a more graceful manner? e.g `Environment.Exit()`**

**-Examples-**

**This will compile:**

```
private string TestMethod(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return "this is a string";
    }
    throw new Exception(); 
    // No point in a return after this, it could never be reached.
}
```

**This will NOT compile:**

```
private string TestMethod(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return "this is a string";
    }
    Environment.Exit(1);
    // This will not compile.
    // "Not all code paths return a value"
    // But, the code would never make it to the return here.
}
```

Comment: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.7.2) as a section about the difference between `return` and `Environment.exit()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Environment.Exit` is nothing but a method as far as the compiler is concerned.

It enforces that the `TestMethod` either return a value or throw an exception. Calling a method that *might* terminate the application or do something completely different is not a valid way to "return" from a method.

Comment: This seems very reasonable to me! Thanks for the input!